# How to grep non-keyboard charaters?

Tags: linux, grep

I'm trying to use `grep` to get all `μs` under a directory, unfortunately, `μ` is not a keyboard character, any ideas?
BTW, for normal keyboard words, I could use

`find / -type f -print | xargs grep -inE <search_word> 2>/dev/null`

to find out all plain text files that contain the search word.

Answer (score 1):

In Bash, you can use the shell's quoting facilities to pass non-ASCII content.  In order to correctly identify the search string, we need to know the encoding of the files you are grepping.  If they are in UTF-8, you need a different search string than if they are in ISO-8859-1 or UTF-16.

If your shell's locale agrees with the contents of the file, this should all work undramatically out of the box, but here are a couple of workarounds.

```
# grep ISO-8859-1 \xB5
grep $'\xB5' file

# grep UTF-8 U+03BC
grep $'\xCE\xBC' file

# grep UTF-16be U+03BC
grep $'\x03\xBC' file

# grep UTF-16le U+03BC
grep $'\xBC\x03' file
```

Some older versions of `grep` have a problem with non-ASCII characters; as a workaround, you can also use Perl.

```
perl -ne  'print if m/\u03BC/' file
```

You might have to play around with [Perl's Unicode facilities](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlunicode.html) to get this to work.

Answer (score 0):

Would You mind using sed instead of grep?

```
sed -n '/\xb5/p'
```

However grep should also work:

```
grep -P '\xb5'
```

Comment: Hi Vlad, thanks for your reply. I tried both of your methods, I got a lot of returned results, some of them are not wanted. However, I could use pipe to grep base on return results to get those I want.

Comment: I guess I should've said: grep -P '\xb5s' (to grep μs, not just μ) ;)